# I have a website into cackephp v1.3.14 and i want to upgrade into cakephp v3.x

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Can I easily upgrade cake PHP v1.3.14 to v3.x ? If it is possible, then what are the changes after upgrading? Give me the best way to how can upgrade it?

Comment: Check here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html
Follow the documentation, it will explain all steps

Answer (score 3):

Since cakephp 1.3 to cakephp 3 there is lot of changes in framework so i would suggest first update to cakephp 2.x and if its ok then continue with it else from 2.x upgrade to 3.x
For updating follow the steps:
Download the cakephp 2.x

1. Then add all your controllers from 1.3 to 2.x, models and views.
2. Then run the code if and fix the errors like functions that are not supported in controller and view.
3. Then optimise the code according the best usage of the latest code.

Here is link for learning cakephp few concepts:
https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html
http://www.onenightstudy.com/search/label/CakePhp